# How to use Fork() to create only 2 child processes which both has next two child?

Tags: c

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
      printf("Parent:my pid: %d my ppid: %d\n",getpid(),getppid() );


      pid_t pid0 = fork();

      if (pid0 == 0) {
        //child 1
        printf("child 1:my pid: %d my ppid: %d\n",getpid(),getppid() );
        pid_t pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 == 0) {
          //child 11
          printf("child 11:my pid: %d my ppid: %d\n",getpid(),getppid() );
        }else if (pid2 > 0) {
          //child 1
          pid_t pid3 = fork();
          if (pid3 == 0) {
            //child 12
            printf("child 12:my pid: %d my ppid: %d\n",getpid(),getppid() );
          }else if (pid3 > 0) {
            //Child 1
          }else{
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork doesn't work\n" );
            return -1;
          }
        }else{
          fprintf(stderr, "Fork doesn't work\n" );
          return -1;
        }
      }else if (pid0 > 0) {
        //patent
        pid_t pid1 = fork();
        if (pid1 == 0) {
          //child 2
          printf("child 2:my pid: %d my ppid: %d\n",getpid(), getppid() );
          pid_t pid4 = fork();
          if (pid4 == 0) {
            //child 21
            printf("child 21 :my pid: %d my ppid: %d\n",getpid(),getppid() );
          }else if (pid4 > 0) {
            //child 2
            pid_t pid5 = fork();
            if (pid5 == 0) {
              //child 22
              printf("child 22 :my pid: %d my ppid: %d\n",getpid(),getppid() );
            }else if (pid5 > 0) {
              //child 2

            }else{
              fprintf(stderr, "Fork doesn't work\n" );
              return -1;
            }
          }else{
            fprintf(stderr, "Fork doesn't work\n" );
            return -1;
          }
        }else if (pid1 > 0) {
          //parent
        }else{
          fprintf(stderr, "Fork doesn't work\n" );
          return -1;
        }
      }else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fork doesn't work\n" );
        return -1;
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Is there any way to create only 2 child processes from the parent which both has next two child? I tried something like this but PPID is not correct with parents PID.
[here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz30n.png)
......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, there is such a way.